# trackpad wheel end event (finger lifted from trackpad)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a wheel end event or how to detect when user lift fingers from trackpad after wheel?

I'm want to achieve animations like macOS launchpad as the gif shown below, so I need to know when user lifted their fingers

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You need to show some effort and not just hope someone else will write all the code for you.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I just want know user lift hands, not the whole animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such event and it's not possible to detect when the user has placed/removed their finger(s) on/from a trackpad.

- The [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) event fires when a physical mouse's wheel is rotated *or* a trackpad gesture is detected by the OS.
- The various [touch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) and [pointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events) events fire for physical mouse movement, button presses, trackpad movement, and/or fingers on a touchscreen.

The basic thing to understand is that a trackpad emulates a traditional, physical mouse.  The trackpad drivers convert touches into cursor movement, button clicks, and "wheel" movement.  At least from the perspective of a web app, there's no way to tell whether the cursor movement is the result of a mouse or a trackpad.

In contrast, browsers make touch input on touchscreen devices available in detail to web apps, and you're able to override default behavior via `preventDefault()`.

The best you'll be able to do is set a timeout after the last `wheel` event.  Reset your timeout after every `wheel` event, and then fire your "end" event after the timeout expires.  You may also want to "end" on `mousemove`, since cursor movement probably means the user took the second finger off the trackpad and started moving one finger.  Although keep in mind, a physical mouse can both move and wheel at the same time.